# Continue winding using another wire

Tags: coil

While winding a coil my wire snapped, I would like to complete winding of the coil and still have a functioning coil?

Will it have any effect on the performance of that coil?

It’s being wound around a ferromagnetic core (some alloy). I wound 200 turns and there are 400 more to go.

What’s the best way to splice the wire?

Comment: How many turns and how far to go? What sort of core is it?

Comment: Current rating will be determined by the smaller of the two wires if you have to change size.  Joints are made routinely in transformer windings in industry for many reasons, using of ends saves money with heavy wires, avoiding joints saves money on fine wires.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, just make sure the joint between the two wires is relatively small and insulated (it being big doesn't really affect it a lot, but you will have trouble winding the rest of the winding.)

It will look ugly though.

Comment: Arrange for the joint to be at one side...

Comment: Also make sure the joint hasn't any sharp edges touching the other windings, as this might eventually damage isolation.

Comment: ...or bring the joint outside the winding area of the coil, as you would a tap, that way there is minimal disturbance to the winding geometry.